# Use HashSet to weed out duplicate values. List returns either empty or returns duplicate values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashset

I am trying to remove duplicate values from an `ArrayList` using `HashSet`, so that city names aren't returned more than once if they are the same… The List comes back either empty or still shows duplicate values. Was hoping someone could tell me where the error is in my code, so that no duplicate values are returned...

I am using this for reference:

`Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(yourList); yourList.clear(); yourList.addAll(set);` , but can't figure out how to make it work in my code. Know it's probably a simple fix, but I've been playing around with it and still hasn't come back right...

Anyone can tell me where I am going wrong here? According to everyone so far the code looks like it should be working... Although it's not...

**SearchCityFragment**

```
public class SearchCityFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Post> mPostList;
    private Set<Post> mPostSet;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CityAdapter mCityAdapter;

    private EditText mSearchBar;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_city, container, false);

        mRelativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_11);
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        mPostList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCityAdapter = new CityAdapter(getContext(), mPostList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCityAdapter);

        mSearchBar = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        mSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                searchCity(s.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void searchCity(String s) {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("city").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff");
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mPostList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        mPostList.clear();
                        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mPostList.add(post);
                        mPostSet = new HashSet<>(mPostList);
                        mPostList.clear();
                        mPostList.addAll(mPostSet);
                        readCity();
                    }
                }

                mCityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readCity() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (mSearchBar.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mPostList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        mPostList.add(post);
                        mPostSet = new HashSet<>(mPostList);
                        mPostList.clear();
                        mPostList.addAll(mPostSet);
                    }

                    mCityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            mActivity = (Activity) context;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that `mPostSet` is a member variable, I can believe it is some sort of race condition or thread interference. Try using a local variable for the set instead.

Comment: Consider using a `LinkedHashSet` so you get a predictable ordering in `mPostList`.

Comment: @AndyTurner is what I have written logical? Does it make sense in that it "should" be working??

Comment: @AndyTurner the local variable didn't work... Same result... Getting back duplicates...

Comment: it looks like it should work; although given that you're doing this each time you add an element, it would be easier to do `if (!list.contains(thing)) list.add(thing);`; or defer the deduplication until after the loop.

Comment: I would still suggest there is some threading effect. Does it work with `mPostList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());`?

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, still getting the duplicate values... So the value that I am trying to obtain from my Post Model class is ```city```, not just post. So do I have to reiterate that *THAT* is the value instead of just ```post``` or something?

Comment: @JMB now do you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to show the post with searched city and you want to show only one such post you can just query the database for post with that city , you don't need to create any arraylist or hashmap.

```
                          private void searchCity(String s) {
                               FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                     .getReference("Posts")
                                     .orderByChild("city")
                                     .startAt(s)
                                     .limitToFirst(1).
                                     .addValueEventListener(new ValueEvnetListener){
                                     @Override
                                     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot 
                                     dataSnapshot) {
                                     // do your rhing
                                      }
                                    @Override
                               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                                    } ;
}
```

Comment: What's searchedCity in this case? Is that the name of the variable for Query?

Comment: the city which is search , as you told me your user is searching a city and you want to show one one post with that city

Comment: no not a name of query variable ,you can create a Query variable thought, i just chained everying

Comment: learn more https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: Yeah, but a user searches for a location that being a city, and for example, each post has an associated city with it... If there is more than one New York for example, New York should only come back once... That city can be any city so I need for "searchedCity" to be a variable for querying all the cities in the database and make sure only one with that specific name comes back, even if there is more than one.

Comment: yes that is why we said `limitToFirst(1)` so the only first one comes , if you don't use that like all of them will be returned in the snapshot

Comment: Okay, what should I put in "searchedCity"?

Comment: the "searchedCity" is a variable of type string , it contains the city you searched , you take it from the search field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216376/discussion-between-jmb-and-abhinav-chauhan).

Comment: That's what I'm talking about! Works :)

Comment: yes, you were just confused from variable name, i should have include the entire method in the first place, so is it working now?

Comment: Yes sir working and I hope it keeps working! Thanks buddy! I was trying to do it with HashSet all day, but it wasn't working... Still don't know why. But for what I need it for it works fine :)

Comment: anytime buddy, you don't have to do things in the hard way, just learn more about the API there are always easy solutions available

Comment: and next time in your question also mention want you are trying , so that instead of making your thing work , people can suggest better solution for that problem, have a good day

Comment: Okay, little problem... Now if for example I have the locations Alaska and Alabama if the user types A, only one comes up... And both should come up because they are two different locations :(

Comment: do show all of them you can remove `.limitToFirst(1)` but them same cities will also come up, in that case you have to loop through the snapshot manually remove the post with duplicate city

Comment: How can we change it so it looks at the entire city name and not just the first letter, because I need it to return all the cities that start with the same letter, but only once

Comment: Okay, can you help me with the manual loop because that's what I need...? We're back to where I started lol